# how to use verbatim within a list

Tags: listings, verbatim

I tried to use `verbatim` within a list like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
Search(HTMLpage, \begin{verbatim}``<TITLE>*</TITLE>''\end{verbatim});
Copy(HTMLpage);
Paste(Title);
\end{lstlisting}
```

but it displayed as:

```
Search(HTMLpage, \begin{verbatim}"<TITLE>∗</TITLE>"\end{verbatim});
Copy(HTMLpage);
Paste(Title);
```

so how to use highlight the `HTML` code in the list?

cheers

Comment: I am confused: Why do you not use the `HTML` language setting for `listings` package?

Comment: The problem here is that [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)'s `lstlisting` environment already changes the input in a way that `verbatim` cannot overcome (since it's nested). One way is to include the `mathescape` option and use `Search(HTMLpage, $\verb|``<TITLE>*</TITLE>''|$); ...` However, perhaps you want to clarify what you're after exactly first.

Comment: @Werner To clarify, what I need is to make the `HTML` code in the listing, looks different to other text, in that to make `<TITLE>*</TITLE>` looks more like source code.

Comment: ps. it seems `mathescape` can't escape `lstlisting`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to create the `verbatim` component in advance of the listing, this can be done...

If you need more than one `verbatim` block per listing, the `myverbbox` environment allows you to give names to the verb-boxes (rather than the default `\theverbbox` as shown here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\small]``<TITLE>*</TITLE>''\end{verbbox}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
Search(HTMLpage, $\theverbbox$);
Copy(HTMLpage);
Paste(Title);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]